# Reduce boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have to reduce this boolean algebra :

((x⊕y)⊕(y⊕z))⊕(x⊕(1⊕((y⊕0)⊕z)))

I found out that

1. ((x⊕y)⊕(y⊕z)) = x⊕z
2. y⊕0 = y
3. 1⊕(y⊕z) = negative(y⊕z)

looking at the solution it must be reducable to negative(y), but i don't know how to get from  (x⊕z)⊕(x⊕negative(y⊕z)) to negative(y)

Comment: What are the elementary principles that hold for this algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next, note that we have $x\oplus \lnot(y\oplus z) = \lnot(x\oplus(y\oplus z))$. In fact, this $\lnot$ can be moved all the way to the front:
$$
\lnot\big((x\oplus z)\oplus(x\oplus(y\oplus z))\big)
$$
Lastly, note that $\oplus$ is both associative and commutative, so we can take away the parentheses and rearrange the terms to get
$$
\lnot (x\oplus x \oplus y \oplus z \oplus z) = \lnot (0\oplus y \oplus 0) = \lnot y
$$

Comment: Wow, how did you get from the question that you can take the negation out like that? And how did you know that the operator is associative and commutative?

Comment: Thanks. I got it ! The note was really helpful :)

Comment: Huh! I still don't get it ...

Comment: @Bram28 $\oplus$ is a common notation for the `XOR` operation. I assumed that that's what it is, since also $y \oplus 0 = y$ and $1 \oplus (y \oplus z) = \lnot (y\oplus z)$.

Comment: @Arthur Oh!  OK, I thought it was some given mystery operator. Got it, thanks!